# Find a line under a line

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on a little program for myself and I'm having issues to find write lines that are under a specific line in a new file.

To be more specific, I have a file that is basically a transcript of a chat, first line is the name of a person, second is the message and third is the name of another person etc.

The chat is made like that (messages censored for privacy reasons):

```
Name1 Firstname1
Message sent by Name1 Firstname1
Name2 Firstname2
Message sent by Name2 Firstname2
Name1 Firstname1
Message sent by Name1 Firstname1
Name1 Firstname1
Message sent by Name1 Firstname1
```

As you can see, the order can be random because someone can have sent multiple message in a row.

I have tried to do that :

```
import re

def Sep(Source, OutputA):
    with open(Source, 'r', encoding='utf8', errors='ignore') as fdin:
        temp = fdin.readlines()
    regex = re.compile(r"^(Name)+ (FirstName)")
    result = [x for x in temp if regex.search(x)]
    with open(OutputA, 'w', encoding='utf8', errors='ignore') as fdout:
        fdout.writelines(result)

Sep('chat.txt','Results.txt')
```

This output 'Name FirstName' in my Results.txt, what i'm trying to do is output the line just after Name FirstName in Results.txt. Any clue would be greatly appreciated ! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it always 2nd line?

Comment: why you even need re? use readlines and when line matches what you look for do something with next line

Comment: It is but I can't search for every 2 lines because it's a chat and it would mix the messages between the person in the chat.

Comment: you should show us a snippet of your chat.txt

Comment: @Drako I don't know, I'm just more comfortable using re as I'm new in python.

Comment: @Boendal I'll update my question with it

Comment: and your expected output are basically 4 lines (`Message...`) ?

Comment: I try to make my output as just a succession of the messages sent by the person I put in my function, one per line.

Comment: check answer and - do you still need re :)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like that:

```
import re

def Sep(Source, OutputA, user_name, user_firstname):
    with open(Source, 'r', encoding='utf8', errors='ignore') as fdin:
        text = fdin.read()

    matches = re.finditer("^({}) ({})\n(.*)".format(user_name,user_firstname),text, re.MULTILINE)
    with open(OutputA, 'w', encoding='utf8', errors='ignore') as fdout:
        for match in matches:
            fdout.write(match.group(3))
            fdout.write("\n")

Sep('chats.txt','Results.txt', "Name1","Firstname1")
```

## Output:

```
Message sent by Name1 Firstname1
Message sent by Name1 Firstname1
Message sent by Name1 Firstname1
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:
contents of test.txt:

```
fdsgdfs
this
after this
sdfgsdfgdfs
```

contents of python file:

```
src = 'test.txt'
s = 'this'

with open(src, 'r') as f:
    for ln in f:
        if s == ln.strip():
            print(next(f))
```

Comment: Thanks, it does work, I'll try to male it work with mine !